# Converting very small numbers

Tags: math, lua, numbers

how can I convert very small numbers in lua?
example 1.75245E-09 or 7.73411E-08
it works to e-04

```
from lua interpreter:
1> 1.75245E-05
1.75245e-05
1> 1.75245E-04
0.000175245
```

Comment: What makes you think that not-really-so-small numbers like ...E-09 do *not* work as expected?!

Comment: http://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html states that LUA uses double-precision floating points, which ["allows the representation of numbers with a decimal exponent between 1E−308 and 1E308"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Look up how to do formatted output in LUA. In C, you have the formats %f for exponentless output, %e for scientific output always with exponent and %g for shortest string among them. The LUA default output looks like %11.6g. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Lua is not an acronym. Stop spelling it "LUA".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [string.format](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format) which works almost exactly as the C print-into-string function `sprintf`.

Thus

```
string.format("%f",7.73411E-08)
```

should yield the desired output. If it is useful to have that many leading zeros is another question. I did not test this, the default length might be limited. If so use

```
string.format("%20f",7.73411E-08)
```

to provide sufficient space.